# Can we record Call of Duty: Online gameplay and replay it?

Tags: call-of-duty-online

I would like to record gameplay of [Call of Duty: Online](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty_Online). Is there a feature for this built in with game client like DOTA2 and LoL?

I don't want to use 3rd party tools or any video recording software like Shadowplay or FRAPS.

I am okay using such 3rd paty tools which make use of 'actual game' to play the replay.
e.g. LOL Replay Client (http://www.leaguereplays.com/)

Comment: @Anaurag - which CoD game **specifically** are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about CoD online version.  
http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty_Online  
Does @h0ch5tr4355 answer work for this?

Comment: thanks :) I've made this clearer in your question. As for the answer that h0ch5tr4355 gave, I am not sure.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but LoL does have no built in recording function. Or did I miss something?

Comment: LoL has LoL replay client(basically 3rd party but doesn't record video files) **which can play replay using LoL Game** which is what I am looking for.I shall rephrase question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes OK. so it can be third party software but no storing in video format which leads to huge amount of data. Nevertheless `/record` is neither 3rd party nor does it store in video format. You have only less MB of data for quite a lot of play time.

Comment: This is the first preference, does it work with Call Of Duty Online?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it would be interesting which

1. Platform
2. Episode

you are playing.

But since you are comparing with LoL and DotA I assume you are playing on the PC and one of the newer episodes.

And so the function you are searching for is a simple console command:

```
/record [file name]
```

This records a so-called *demo* and puts it in the folder similar to: `Call Of Duty/main/demos`. The file name extension of the demos is `*.dm2`.

To play a demo you have to use the command:

```
/demo [file name]
```

There is an autocomplete in CoD's console which is supposed to help you with the syntax.

Comment: It might be worth noting which CoD was the first to have this feature.

Comment: I am not sure about CoD 1, but any other has it - maybe a bit different regarding the path e.g. but thats why I wrote the last sentence. There are description in the console which lead you ;-)

Comment: Ok but just to be clear when you say CoD 1 do you mean the first Call of Duty or *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare*? Because I've had people get confused before and think that Modern Warfare was the first one, when technically it's the 4th :)

Comment: Ok thank you for the hint and i am talking about the real CoD1 but i think noone would come here for CoD1 so i posted the answer anyway :-D

Comment: I am looking for Call of Duty: online game. Does above answer work for it?

Comment: @AnuragDaware Wasn't aware of CoD Online since it is only published in China as I read now but the Developer is still Activision and so I assume the answer should still be correct. Just try it out via the record function, be aware that you have probably to activate the console in the game settings and set a keyboard shortcut for it.

Comment: ok I shall try this solution.

Comment: I am trying this but not able to find console. How to open console?

Comment: There should be an option in the settings. Not mandatory in the settings for the keyboard control.